# What exactly does Yii email's validator validate?

Tags: php, email, yii, validation

This is probably a silly question, but i could't figure it out. I have the following:

```
array('email', 'email','message'=>'The email isn´t correct'),
```

What would this validation validate exactly? That the input text contains '@' and a '.' ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The validator uses a regular expression to validate the email.

For the specific expression it uses, look at [the source](http://code.google.com/p/yii/source/browse/tags/1.1.8/framework/validators/CEmailValidator.php). You can then use an online RegEx tool to quickly check if the regex matches any particular input.

Answer (score 7):

Yii is a great framework for form validation,today i am going to show you how to validate the email field in the form before submitting.Its very simple just follow the below example.

if you created a user model with email as one attribute then in the rules function add the following code.

```
public function rules() {
   return array(
     ...
     array('email', 'email','checkMX'=>true), 
     ...
); }
```

thats it